# Frequency ratio test with correlation structures

Tags: sas, binomial-distribution, reliability, frequency

I have some data about two machines, each machine has 10-15 operation logs, and inside the log are the time-stamped status checks that takes on the value of `1` if there is a warning and `0` otherwise.

The question is to decide which machine is better? (in terms of less warnings in the log)

I am thinking of the two approaches to test the difference:

1. Assuming that each status check is independent (both within- and between-operations), that way the problem becomes a typical frequency count test and I can apply proc `freq` in SAS.
2. Because the records comes from different operation logs, I wonder if I should factor in the operation into the test? In other words, is there any frequency test that considers the possible correlation of status within each operation?

Answer (score 1):

In that case I think that maybe you can use the logs as a covariate and fit a regression model for counts.  Maybe Poisson regression or Negative binomial regression.